# Use javascript source-maps with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, source-maps

we are shipping a Cordova WebApp for tablets with minified source using uglify2-compressor via grunt-contrib-requirejs. We generate source-maps for debugging which work flawlessly using the chrome desktop browser via remote Debugging on a KitKat Android Tablet.

Now we like to send error reports from our customers to our server. The Android WebView does not seem to care about our source maps. Therefore we get error message like "line 1, char 1231231" - not very helpful...

The Question is: Is it possible to use source-maps with the Android (and iOS) Webview maybe using a Cordova plugin or do we have to wait for an update (Chrome and Firefox Desktop are able to parse the maps...) and ship un-minifies code so that we are able to get the line number of the occurred error?

Answer (score 0):

From [Chromium discuss topic](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/c54b6CxWhwU)

> DevTools downloads source maps using the front-end browser, not the one that runs the inspected page. So file://android... is never going to be accessible. You need to point to the files on your development box instead.